# How to get image from Cloudinary and cache them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, curl, nginx, cloudinary

I need to get images from **Cloudinary** to my server and handle them as much as I feel like to. I need to **cache** the images and Cloudinary does not help. I'd like to get the images using curl or anything but **nginx**.

In my **views**:

```
background:url(<%=
cached_cloudinary_image_path(@landing.background_image_id,
transformation: [ { width: 1024, height: 200, quality: 60, crop:
:fill, gravity: :south, dpr: :auto }, { effect:
"contrast:-50/e_brightness:0/e_blur:400" } ]) %>) center 100%
no-repeat;
```

Where `@landing.background_image_id` is ok. This works in development.

In my `application_controller.rb` I have:

```
def cached_cloudinary_image_tag cloudinary_url, *args
    if Rails.env.development?
      cl_image_tag cloudinary_url, *args
    else
      image_tag cached_cloudinary_image_path(cloudinary_url), *args
    end
  end

  def cached_cloudinary_image_path cloudinary_url, *args
    if Rails.env.development?
      cl_image_path cloudinary_url, *args
    else
      cloudinary_url = cl_image_path cloudinary_url, *args 
      cloudinary_url.gsub(/http(s?)\:\/\/(.*)cloudinary.com/, "https://mysite .com/cached")
    end
  end
```

The latter replaces the image with my **"proxy"** and the images are not displayed.

How can I solve this?